# Can I write a congruence like this?

Tags: notation, modular-arithmetic

I wrote down the following

$\omega_e(P) \equiv 0,n\pmod{\! k}$, where $n|k$.

What I'm trying to say is that $\omega_e(P)$ is either congruent to $0$ mod $k$ or $n$ mod $k$.

Is this the correct way to write it down?

Comment: Is $n$ supposed to be **any** factor of $k$, or **some specific** factor of $k$?

Comment: any factor of $k$

Comment: It is often used, but *beware*: compare $\,x\equiv 0,n\pmod{\!k}\,$ vs. $\,k\mid x,x\!-\!n.\,$ In the former the comma means "or", but it usually means "and" in the latter, so the notation is not well-behaved in terms of equational logic (its meaning changes when we replace a congruence by its equivalent divisibility form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't like writing things like this. Just like I wouldn't write the solutions to $x^2-1=0$ as $x=1,-1$. Rather, I would write $x=1$ or $x=-1$.

Here, I would write $\omega_e(P)\equiv 0\pmod{k}$ or $\omega_e(P)\equiv n\pmod{k}$ for some $n$ which divides $k$.

Note that no matter what, you should add some words to clearly show that $n$ is still a variable, to answer @David's question in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that, yes, you can write it like this. I know some would prefer to say
$\omega_e(P) \equiv 0 \; (\mathrm{mod}\ k) $, or $\omega_e(P) \equiv n \; (\mathrm{mod}\ k) $.

Personally, I like the brevity of the comma, and readers know what you are trying to say. Ultimately though, it doesn't really matter and it's up to you. I've seen the comma used more in published math though.